# Teams bot authentication, not using Builder.Dialog

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I made a simple "bot" for Microsoft Teams, based on the [sample echo bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot). This bot forwards messages to a dialog API and back to the user.

My goal is to fetch Active Directory properties for the current user.

This is why I am trying to add [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample) to my code. From what I understand, one of the first steps is to send the user a special message containing a OAuth card as attachment. **I can't figure out how to create the "*SignInLink*" for this card.**

---

The [teams auth sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L23) will call `OAuthPrompt.SendOAuthCardAsync`. [Which code](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/OAuthPrompt.cs#L117) calls `UserTokenAccess.GetSignInResourceAsync(turnContext, settings, cancellationToken)`. The return value is the SignInLink.

This whole thing require at some point a `ConnectionName` being configured and I do not have such thing. I think this thing [is generated when you create a bot in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample#prepare-the-bot-sample-code); but I do not wish to host in Azure.

Digging deeper, the [`BotSignIn.GetSignInUrlWithHttpMessagesAsync` method](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/60c70ca7e84ec929faf73af4e171639b013c7285/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/BotSignIn.cs#L61) is in charge of creating the SignInLink. I would like to call that but there are too many cryptic parameters. Am I on the right track?

---

Notes and environment:

1. Coding in Rider under Windows and Linux.
2. Hosting on Linux server behind a load balancer (TLS).
3. Project targets `netcoreapp2.1` (I am open to update if necessary).
4. The [Teams Authentication sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) uses the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs` framework which I do not wish to use.
5. I want to be able to call [`microsoft.graph/me`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to fetch AD user properties.
6. I created an app registration within *aad.portal.azure.com* and enabled "*Allow public client flows*".

Comment: Is there any reason, do not host in Azure?
Microsoft Graph is a RESTful web API that enables you to access Microsoft Cloud service resources. After you register your app and get authentication tokens for a user or service, you can make requests to the Microsoft Graph API.
Ref. Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT we are not using Azure because have a hosting cluster and do not wish to maintain another one. If the Teams ecosystem is not open for consuming from out of Azure, we will consider using Azure.